# How to pop continuos values from a queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, queue, self

Below is the code to implement a priority queue to implement a first come first serve basis or service but if a customer is a VIP(priority) then they are to be served before the regular customers.

How do I pop values without the values going away? The code is followed by the output which is empty for function waiting as all the values are popped.

```
Class myQueue():
    def enqueue(self, data,vip):
      
        if vip==1:
            self.queue2.insert(0, data)

        else:
            self.queue.insert(0,data)

    def dequeue(self):
    
        while len(self.queue2) > 0:
            return self.queue2.pop()
        else:
            return self.queue.pop()

    def waiting(self):

        self.queue.reverse()
        self.queue2.reverse()
        self.queue2.extend(self.queue)
        return self.queue2

myQueue = Queue()
myQueue.enqueue(10,0) # return True
myQueue.enqueue(5,1)
myQueue.enqueue(6,0)
myQueue.enqueue(11,1) 
print(myQueue.waiting())
```

Output:

```
5
11
10
6
[]
```

The problem here is that after the values are popped they are no longer available for calling the waiting() method, if I use the copy function then the values from deque() always pop the same value.

If I replace the below code in deque, I get the following output:

```
while len(self.queue2) > 0:
    return self.queue2.copy().pop()
else:
    return self.queue..copy().pop()
```

Output:

```
5
5
5
5
[5, 11, 10, 6]
```

I get the waiting output correctly but deque gets messed up.

Expected Output:

```
5
11
10
6
[5, 11, 10, 6]
```

Comment: What are the values present in queue and queue2?

Comment: What do you pass as an input argument to dequeue and waiting functions??

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it those functions are supposed to do?

Comment: I have updated the question, hope it's no longer an xy problem